# Show that this vector identity is true using divergence theorem:

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

Show that $$ \int_{V'}{\pmb{\nabla}' \times \frac{\pmb{F}(\pmb{r}')}{|\pmb{r}-\pmb{r}'|} }\,dV' \equiv \int_{S'}{\pmb{n}'\,\times\frac{\pmb{F}(\pmb{r}')}{|\pmb{r}-\pmb{r}'|}}\,dS'$$ where $\pmb{n}'$ is the outward pointing unit vector of the surface S' that bounds V', and $\pmb{F}(\pmb{r})$ is a 3-dimensional vector-valued function.

**Hint**: the integral conversion involves the Divergence Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** It seems to me that if u is a constant vector one has
$$\nabla\cdot (G\times u) = u\cdot(\nabla\times G)$$
and
$$n\cdot (G\times u) = u\cdot(n\times G)$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction +Gribouillis. I found this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1283417/491258. I didn't realize that the integral above is a vector identity, it was just a consequence of something I was proving for myself. Haha in many ways, my question was useless, no? I really appreciate your time though, best wishes.